# Ajax auto complete data showing with delay

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have use ajax-jquery autocomplete for a search module , but when i type a single charactor it takes some time to load data , how can i make it quick and make the drop down floating smooth ..

Please advice

ajax code

```
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("1234");

 $searcho=$_GET["term"];
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sltdb_cddir_content where title like '%".$searcho."%'AND categories_id=80 order by title ASC ");
 $json=array();
    while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $display["title"],
                    'label'=>$display["title"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);
```

jquery

```
jQuery(function(){
           jQuery( "#addresso" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo JURI::root().'modules/mod_jomdirectory_search/tmpl/org-address.php'; ?>",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            searcho : jQuery('#searcho').val(),
                            addresso : jQuery('#addresso').val()
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.addresso ,
                                    value: item.addresso
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
```

Comment: You should open up some developer tool like Firebug and start seeing where the delay is occurring.  This will have profound impacts on how you will optimize.

Comment: Also the jQuery UI autocomplete [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay) has a bit about the default delay imposed on the client side.

Comment: @Jason Sperske : thanks for the advice. by the way i want to make the drop down appearing in smoothly  as well.how can do that ? is there any specifc class can use from jqiery ui ?

Comment: I don't think the jQueryUI widget has a callback hook for that.